# scrapy append to linkextractor links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using `CrawlSpider` with `LinkExtractor` to crawl the links.

How would I go about appending parameters to the links `LinkExtractor` finds?  I would like to add `'?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999'` to each link that `LinkExtractor`extracts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for using [`process_value` argument](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor):

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

addition = "?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999"

LinkExtractor(process_value=lambda x: x + addition)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I have an issue now where `addition` is added mutiple times `?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999?pag_sortorder=0&pag_perPage=999`.

Comment: @EliquidVape could you please share the complete code you have at the moment, so I can reproduce the problem and debug it? thanks!